# Why i cant install php-mbstring in ubunto?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Good afternoon community, well I have changed from S.O from fedora to ubuntu for compatibility with my graphics card, well my problem is that I cannot install the php-mbstring package and I get this error in console [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgOUZ.png)

```
➜  ~ sudo apt install php7.4-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-mbstring : Depends: libonig5 (>= 6.8.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do you have any idea what might be happening? Cheers

Comment: Ideally add more details about your current OS to your post, like the output of uname -a